# cant add a field to a returned query in cakephp4 in a loop

Tags: php, cakephp, orm, cakephp-4.x

In cakephp4 have have a returned data from a query (array of objects)  . I want to add a field to each  eg

In my controller i have
$daysLessons=$this->Lessons->getSchedule($searchFirstName..);

```
printed out the data looks like 
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "fred",
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "dave",
    }
```

so i want to add a field to each row which i cant seem to do in cakephp 4

```
 foreach(  $daysLessons as $key => $value){
         $daysLessons{$key}->systemtime=date('H:i:s');  //Cannot use object of type Cake\ORM\Query as array
         $daysLessons[$key]->systemtime=date('H:i:s');  //Cannot use object of type Cake\ORM\Query as array
         $daysLessons[$key]['systemtime']=date('H:i:s'); //Cannot use object of type Cake\ORM\Query as array
         $value->systemtime=date('H:i:s'); //no error but not permanent

     }
```

I am not sure how to append to an existing result set from a query , and checking the docs i cant see anything  either.

Comment: You want to use a [**result formatter**](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/query-builder.html#adding-calculated-fields).

Comment: no i need unrelated fields, not more ways to get data from the database. This is not what I want. Above is what I need

Comment: This isn't about getting more fields from the database, it is about exactly what you're asking for, adding arbitrary data to the resultset.